# Goland debug go got hanged. Goland 2022.2.4

Tags: go, debugging, goland

When I click the button(Debug TestFunc), it stoped at the first breakpoint,[image1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lJO48.png).

If click F8, it hang on and the Console kept loading,[image2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6QEHl.png).

If click F9, it stoped at the second breakpoint

It's very strange because this problem only happen in TestFunc,
if I move the code in main function, F8,F9 work normal

Go go1.18.3 darwin/arm64
hardware MacBook Pro (13-inch, M1, 2020)
dlv version 1.9.1

nothing, just restore the normal TestFunc Debuging

Comment: there is no problem `go 1.19.1`, `goland 2022.2.4`, maybe you can change the golang's version

Answer (score 0):

Please file an issue in GoLand issue tracker: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/newIssue?project=GO